# Is there a way to reduce the number of producers?

Tags: producers

Trying to reduce 3 out of 9 producers
I ran the unregprod command, but it doesn't seem to be applied. Is there a way to reduce the producer?

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your question? It's hard to understand what you really mean by your question.

Comment: I am considering how to delete the producer from the producer table. If I do this, will the producer be excluded from the scheduler?